# How to use drag as a 'function' instead of a 'var'?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

First off I was using this for dragging objects on screen :

```
var button_drag = d3.behavior.drag()
             d3.behavior.drag()
             .origin(function() {
                var g = this;
                return {x: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[0],
                        y: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[1]};
            })
            .on("drag", function(d) {

                g = this;
                translate = d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate;

                x = d3.event.dx + translate[0],
                y = d3.event.dy + translate[1];

                //boundaries

                // if(x<10){x=10}
                // if(x>100){x=100}
                if(y<10){y=10}
                if(y>200){y=200}

                d3.select(g).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
                d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();             
            });
```

call it like so :

```
buttons.call(buttons_drag);
```

Now I want to change this to a function so I can pass variables through it to set different boundaries for different objects:

```
function button_drag(xLower,xhigher,yLower,yHigher){
    d3.behavior.drag()
             .origin(function() {
                var g = this;
                return {x: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[0],
                        y: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[1]};
            })
            .on("drag", function(d) {

                g = this;
                translate = d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate;

                x = d3.event.dx + translate[0],
                y = d3.event.dy + translate[1];

                //boundaries

                if(x<xLower){x=xLower}
                if(x>xHigher){x=xHigher}
                if(y<yLower){y=-yLower}
                if(y>yHigher){y=yHigher}

                d3.select(g).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
                d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();             
            });
}
```

Then call it like so :

```
buttons.call(buttons_drag(xLower,xHigher,yLower,yHigher));
```

Once I changed it to a function the whole drag capability doesn't seem to work at all and I'm not too sure why.

Should I be doing this a different way ? Basically all I want to do is to use one drag function for all objects but pass through 'boundaries' when I call the drag function.

Comment: Put a `return` in front of `d3.behavior.drag`. In contrast to your first version, in the second one `buttons.call()` never gets a reference to the drag handler.

Comment: perfect. All works, thankyou. You want to put it in the answers and Ill chose that as the right one ? Thanks again @Sirko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it currently stand, your `buttons.call()` function never receives a handler of the drag behavior. Previously you gave it the return value of the `d3.behavior.drag()` call, but you function later on does not return that reference.

So just add a `return` and you'll be fine:

```
function button_drag(xLower,xhigher,yLower,yHigher){
  return d3.behavior.drag()
  // ...
}
```